# Can Mindsdb predict a new row based on previous rows?

Tags: python, machine-learning, github, mindsdb

I am experimenting with [Mindsdb](https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb), a program to do machine learning with a few codes.

So far as per my understanding after reading their tutorial docs, I assume that this program is to predict a new element of a new row of a table (in an excel file like csv, xlxs, etc), with a massive quantity of rows that are in the same format above it as data. It learns from the "data" and set up an algorithm to predict a new element (new column) of the new row, with a/some known (pre-given) value of element (column) in that row.

I wonder if it can predict an entire new row without knowing any element's value of that row, only based on the previous rows. I asked Mindsdb on the main page (email), facebook, youtube and got no answer.

If anyone is using Mindsdb and understand it, do you know if Mindsdb is able to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *not* possible to predict a new row per say, but you can format your data in such a way as to achieve this.

Let's say you have the following data:

```
col1, col2
1       2
4       8
16      32
64      128
```

And you want to predict the next row (in this case it's obviously going to be `256` in `col1` and `512` in `col2`).

Mindsdb is meant to learn to predict one or multiple columns from a bunch of other columns, and it does so on a row by row basis, so it doesn't know what the "last row" was.

However, you can be a bit more explicit and modify the data above to be:

```
col1, col2, col1_next, col2_next
1       2       4           8
4       8       16          32
16      32      64          128
```

and on this dataset, given the row:

```
col1, col2, col1_next, col2_next
64     128      ?          ?
```

You could have mindsdb predict the "next row" by predicting `col1_next` and `col2_next`.

Example of how that would be done:

```
import mindsdb
import pandas as pd


predictor = mindsdb.Predictor(name='example')
predictor.learn(from_data='<your data source>', to_predict=['col1_next', 'col2_next'])

predictor.predict(when={'col1': 64, 'col2':128}) # This will yield a prediction for col1_next and col2_next
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good way to achieve the goal. Although my table has like 27 columns, the arrangement will be real hard. But I will try. Is there any tool to make the arrangement easier?

Comment: Nevermind. That is irrelevant. It is only hard at my data gathering process.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is what George mentioned.

The other way is by using timerseries prediction, have a look at the link.
https://docs.mindsdb.com/tutorials/AdvancedExamples/